# Firebase Commands on VS Code- Errors

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cloning

I'm a beginner as a developer and I'm having trouble running a React app on Firebase. I have already installed Node.js and npm, and I'm using VS Code as my code editor.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. I wanted to create netflix clone app
2. I finished developing Front-end using ReactJS
3. I set up account and added project in Firebase
4. I installed Firebase tools but whenever I try `firebase login` I get the following error in the terminal.

> Firebase: File `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1`
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see  about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
> + Firebase login
> + CategoryInfo: SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId: UnauthorizedAccess

What might be causing this issue? How I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ExecutionPolicy is probably set to "Restricted", which is why the `.ps1` file gets blocked from running. You can check your ExecutionPolicy status by opening a windows powershell and execute the following command:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

As far as I know you want to set it to "RemoteSigned" in your case.
To change the ExecutionPolicy you can run the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

This should solve your problem. If you want to know more about the ExecutionPolicies you can read it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.4).